# No such file or directory when read file .mat

Tags: python

I'm trying to load file.mat but it say"[Errno 2] No such file or directory"
this is my code
thank you in advanced

```
from scipy.io import loadmat

mnist_raw=loadmat("C:\Users\charo\เดสก์ท็อป\Python\ext-file\"mnist-original.mat")

print(mnist_raw)
```

[image]

Comment: if you look on the error message it says that ML4.py can't be found. Check to make sure you're in the right directory when you try to run the script. Looking at your shell it says you're in C:/Users/charo rather than C:\Users\charo\เดสก์ท็อป\Python\ext-file\ML4.py

Comment: Please, consider error messages you're getting, they are intended to be useful.

Comment: thank you sir i solve it now it have problem about path sir

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a raw string. Also there seems to be an extra double quote before the actual filename?

```
loadmat(r"C:\Users\charo\เดสก์ท็อป\Python\ext-file\mnist-original.mat")
```

or escaping your backslashes

```
loadmat("C:\\Users\\charo\\เดสก์ท็อป\\Python\\ext-file\\mnist-original.mat")
```

Comment: from scipy.io import loadmat

mnist_raw=loadmat("C:\\Users\\charo\\เดสก์ท็อป\\Python\ext-file\\mnist-original.mat")

print(mnist_raw)

Comment: i very new for python now, thankyou for your advice sir

Comment: i can run it now sir  , it have problem with path I make new folder and copy code to there  and its work. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You used " before mnist-original in your path.
Please remove these and check the result.